# Using a String to Instantiate an object in Greenfoot?

Tags: java, greenfoot

So, as part of my college coursework we are working in teams to develop simplistic games in **Greenfoot**, partly to develop on teamwork skills, and partly for actual programming.
Our game features a perlin/simplex generated map to render tessellated terrain tiles for our gameplay, however I need a way to reference the tiles individually, in order for a given tile to interact with it's neighbours.
 Is there an easy way I can instantiate a *worldTile* object by passing a string such as their x/y coordinates (eg *ter_12_142*)? Or is there a simpler method to go about this?

Here's my code for placing tiles in the world;

```js
private void tilePlacement() {

  for (int y = 1; y < rows - 1; y++) {
    for (int x = 2; x < cols - (cols / 4); x++) {

      int w = (getColor(noise[x][y][0]));
      int isAForest = (isForest(noise[x][y][1]));

      addObject(new worldTile(w, isAForest), x * scl, y * scl);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your code _in_ the question, not as a link. if it's too big, reduce it to provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is in the question, using the "attach code snippet" thing that Stackoverflow provides. Apologies if this is inappropriate use of the tool. *changed snippet default setting*

Comment: maybe, but now the question is much better.